# Hard drive not found after blue-screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, power-supply

I met a blue-screen and then a problem saying "Hard drive not found" when I was re-booting my system. But when I plug the power cable of the hard drive and re-insert it, the system can be successfully booted and can be normally run.

Such problems were met several times, all occurring some time (several days) after normal running of the system. In fact, I have changed the hard drive for that problem. But the new drive still has the old problem. I wonder what is wrong. My system is 64-bit Win7 Enterprise Edition. The hard drive is WDC WD10EALX-759BA1 ATA.

Comment: Is it possible the cable doesn't fit well? It sounds like the vibrations of the machine or environment are causing it to become loose. Or maybe the cable is damaged? Use a different cable(s)

Comment: Hi, @DaveRook , thanks for your reminding. I will have a look at that. I recall that the cooling fan of the power part sometimes vibrates intensively. This might be the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Please do let us know if this helps or not

Comment: OK, I am contacting the manufacturer for replacing. It may take some time.

Comment: I think it works.I had the power replaced and haven't found any bluescreen these days. @DaveRook

Comment: I moved my comment to an aswer, I'm glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a power issue

Make sure the cables are connected and the connection is tight so they can't vibrate loose.

Or, try a different PSU

Comment: Yeah, the vibration is due to something stuck in the cooling fan of the PSU.